# Настройка vim, установка плагинов для ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

Решил изучать ruby, вместе с ruby on rails и начал с установки ide. Почитал на форумах, что vim с плагинами очень хорошо подойдет (да и вообще давно хотел научиться им пользоваться). Научился более или менее им пользоваться и сел за установку плагинов. Толком на неё нашел мануалов и ничего не смог сделать.

Как правильно настроить vim для ruby, и, если это возможно, накидать список полезных репозиториеф с плагинами? Или просто закидать ссылками с материалами на эту тему. Сижу на ubuntu (а точнее elemtaryOS).

Заранее спасибо. Всем + к карме.

Comment: То есть, вы собираетесь изучать сразу Ruby, Ruby on Rails и Vim одновременно? А в зависимости от того, что вы ещё умеете, SQL, HTTP, Linux-администрирование? А может, всё-таки лучше начать с чего-то одного?

Comment: ну на linux я давно, знаю хорошо java, а на vim уже кое-чему научился,  так что да, буду изучать одновременно, хотя если с этим будут проблемы, то придется наверное учить по одиночке